# How to programmatically group and set the position of pictures in a word document using access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am currently trying to insert pictures into a word document using access, I currently have a form with a button that uses a folder browser to search for pictures...these pictures are stored in a table!.

I can then select those pictures and insert them into a document, this all goes well, the problem is...I need to then group them (maximum 4 pictures in one group) after days of searching I cannot find any solutions to my problem.

It seems that I must first discover the position of the pictures and then I can go further, the problem there is...that there can be many pictures in total in the document so they do not have a fixed point and there is text between and after the pictures.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Record this action in the Word Macro recorder. Then try adapting the resulting VBA code in Access.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable and controlable approach is to place the pictures in table cells. In your case, probably a 2x2 table. Insert the table first (Tables.Add method) then get the target Cell.Range and use the Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture method to insert the picture.

Note that you should be able to control the width (or height) of the picture by setting the column (row) to an EXACT size. The other dimension should adjust automatically to retain the proportions.

Comment: Hi Cindy, I will have a try at this method...however! I am still what you would probably call a Novice :-) I will look into finding some code examples to point me in the right direction. Unless you know of any yourself? anyway thank you for your reply, I will have a bash at it after I get back from eating.

Comment: I don't know of any code samples that do exactly what I outline, but using the object model methods I mentioned you should be able to turn up enough to get you going. Also, you can test things out in Word (such as setting width/height) and record the actions in a macro. That will give you the basic syntax you need.

Comment: If you hit obstacles, probably best to start a new question for each specific problem and show the code you have working up to that point. If you're getting an error, provide the error information and the line that causes it.